# Unitary matrix in trace and log function

Tags: matrices, logarithms, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, trace

I am trying to do a unitary transformation $U$ on square matrix $A$ which is embedded inside a trace and natural log function, and the following property is supposed to hold:

$\mathrm{tr} (\ln (A)) = \mathrm{tr} (\ln (UAU^\dagger))$

What property of the $\mathrm{tr}$ and $\ln$ functions would allow us to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trace is invariant under cyclic permutations. That is, $tr(ABC) = tr(CAB) = tr(BCA)$. Trace is also linear.

Now, plug in the series for $\log$ for the right hand side, use the fact that $(U A U^+)^n = U A^n U^+$ and linearity of trace to get a sum of $tr(U A^n U^+) = tr (A^n U^+ U) = tr(A^n)$. Then, match that to the expansion you get for tr(ln(A)) in the same way.

Comment: @ Batman , if you consider the principal log., then what is the expansion ? In particular $\log(I+U)=\cdots$ works only when $||A||<1$.  1. Here $sp(A)=sp(UAU^*)$ implies that $sp(\log(A))=sp(\log(UAU^*))$; where is the problem ? 2. If you want to use the expansion, then you can extend your result by extension of inequalities between holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1):

A [corollary of Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#A_Lie_group_theory_perspective) for invertible matrices is $${\rm tr}\log X = \log\det X$$
Applying it to this problem yields
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm tr}\log(UAU^{\dagger})&= \log\det(UAU^{\dagger}) \cr
    &= \log\det(A) \cr
    &= {\rm tr}\log(A) \cr
}$$

Comment: @ greg , your formula is false over the complex matrices. Assume for example, that we consider the "principal" log. (in particular $X$ has no $<0$ eigenvalues);  put $X=diag(e^{2i\pi/3},e^{2i\pi/3})$. Then $tr(\log(X))=4i\pi /3$ and $\log(\det(X))=\log(e^{4i\pi/3})=-2i\pi/3$

Comment: @loupblanc You lost me on that last step: $$\eqalign{\log(e^{4i\pi/3}) &= 4i\pi/3 \cr &\ne -2i\pi/3}$$

Comment: @ john316 , I consider the principal $\log$ that is defined over complex numbers as follows. Let $D=\{z; z\leq 0\}$; if $z\notin D$, then $\theta(z)$ denotes the measure of the angle $(Ox,z)$ that is in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and  $\log(z)$ is, by definition, $\log(r)+i\theta(z)$. Here $\log(e^{4i\pi/3})=-2i\pi/3$. Note that $\log(A)$ is defined for a matrix $A$ that has no $<0$ eigenvalues.