# A series expansion for logarithm of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms, power-series, trace

> Show that $$\operatorname{trace}(A\ln A)=\operatorname{trace}(UAU^\dagger\ln[UAU^\dagger])$$
>   where $U$ is a unitary matrix, i.e. $U^\dagger U=I\iff U^\dagger=U^{-1}$, and $A$ is a hermitian matrix, i.e. $A^\dagger=A$.

**Attempt:**

I read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576775/unitary-matrix-in-trace-and-log-function) but do not fully understand the approach taken by the accepted answer - namely that I don't know what series is being used for the logarithm function. If there were such a series, then $$\ln(X)=\sum_n a_nX^n$$ which gives $\ln[UAU^\dagger]=\sum_na_nUA^nU^\dagger=U\ln [A]U^\dagger$, and so $$\operatorname{trace}(UAU^\dagger\ln[UAU^\dagger])=\operatorname{trace}(UAU^\dagger U\ln [A]U^\dagger)=\operatorname{trace}(UA\ln[A]U^\dagger)=\operatorname{trace}(A\ln [A])$$
where the last step is due to the cyclic property of trace. So this approach seems to work, except for the step where the series was introduced.

**Question:**

What is the series that can be used here? The only series I am aware of is for $\ln(1+x)$, and I am not sure if that can be useful here. Also would there be any convergence issues with this?

I also tried $\ln(x)=(x-1)-\frac12(x-1)^2+\frac13(x-1)^3-\cdots$, but to no avail, since $(UAU^\dagger-I)^n$ doesn't simplify nicely to something like $(UA^nU^\dagger-I)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is presumably using the functional calculus with the function $f(x) = x \ln x$ (defined to be $0$ when $x=0$; any branch of the logarithm is used for $x < 0$).  For any function $f$ defined on the spectrum of the hermitian matrix $A$, $f(A) = p(A)$ if $p$ is a polynomial such that $f(\lambda) = p(\lambda)$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$.  Thus there is no need for series: it's simply that $$\text{trace }p(A) = \text{trace }(U p(A) U^\dagger) = \text{trace }(p(U A U^\dagger))$$ for all polynomials $p$.

Comment: This makes sense, though I was hoping for something more elementary. I have a question about your answer - you seem to be quoting some theorem or result: _$f(A)=p(A)$ if $p$ is a polynomial such that $f(\lambda)=p(\lambda)$ for all eigenvalues of $A$._ What result is this? Also, how do you know of the existence of such a polynomial $p$? Finally, does any of this change in the case of these matrices being infinite dimensional (since this isn't prohibited by the question)? Thank you!

Comment: This can be taken as the definition of the functional calculus for hermitian matrices.  Of course you need to develop various properties of this to see that it's useful.  The polynomial $p$ can be found using Lagrange interpolation.  There are generalizations to "infinite matrices" in the sense of bounded linear operators on Hilbert space, with the continuous functional calculus (related to the Spectral Theorem for self-adjoint operators)  Of course the trace is not defined in general, but you can consider trace-class operators.